# Website Loading Problems

Tags: web

So I have a website, tildetictac.atwebpages.com that gives me an unable to connect error when I access it from my pc on mediacom wifi, but I can access fine from my phone, on Verizon 4g lte.  I was able to access the site last night.

I get this error message: 
    The connection has timed out

The server at tildetictac.atwebpages.com is taking too long to respond.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

And the dashboard from my hosting provider says everything is good, there is no firewall on the site and just plain ole windows defender on my pc.  There are no firewalls on my phone.  I'm not sure how to diagnose the problem.  The error message is vague, every other website works fine from both my computer and my phone.  Are there any unique problems with websites using free subdomains?  The hosting company is reputable and says the site is fine so I doubt the problem is on there side, I have tried multiple browsers on my pc and I don't have anything besides default browser settings.  And my websites gets about 0 traffic so its not overloaded.  This problem has persisted for several hours.

Ok, so i've waited a few days and other computers on my same wifi network can actually access this website.  Infact, my PC is capable of accessing it from a default settings debian based os, but cannot access the site when running on a windows 10 based os.

So, on my problematic windows os i ran nslookup and then a pingtrace and got this

```
> tildetictac.atwebpages.com
Server:  hitronhub.home
Address:  2604:2d80:8402:8b4f:be4d:fbff:fecd:aa02

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    tildetictac.atwebpages.com
Address:  83.125.22.172

> pingtrace 83.125.22.172
Server:  [83.125.22.172]
Address:  83.125.22.172

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to 83.125.22.172 timed-out
```

So the domain name is getting resolved right?  I mean nslookup said it was fine so why is the dns request timing out?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue.  Have you just started hosting the site?  Last 24 hours or so?

Comment: Yeah about 24 hours.  Is there anything I could do to resolve that?

Comment: You'll just have to wait.  It takes time for DNS servers to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to debug the server from various machines using command line tools:  nslookup, ping, curl/links, or telnet?

i would try these from different machines:
`nslookup tildetictac.atwebpages.com 
or
ping tildetictac.atwebpages.com`

the IP address results should be the same even on different machines.  if they aren't, there would be indeed DNS issues as suggested by the other responses.

if the above show no errors, and the lookup/ping respond with an IP address, i would proceed to run:

`curl tildetictac.atwebpages.com
or
links tildetictac.atwebpages.com`

the results should be some HTML code.  on the same machine where the commands error out, i would run the following command to see if the machine can access the server's webport:

`telnet tildetictac.atwebpages.com 80`

i tried to hit the address `tildetictac.atwebpages.com` from my firefox and i saw like an empty page with "Browse" and "Upload" buttons.  Is that right?

Edit: fixed grammar

Comment: tried telnet, didn't work.  This was made very recently so im gonna wait for another day or so for the dns server to update, then if it doesn't work I'm gonna download a few of these and give them a whirl

Comment: these commands should come with most linux boxes. (curl, nslookup, links, telnet may need to be installed.) ping comes with windows. good luck.